# How to take Backup of the Object Storage created in IBM Bluemix (IBM Cloud)?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a Cloud Object storage created from bluemix (IBM Cloud) console. Now for some reason, I need to backup all the data present in the existing object storage into another object storage.

I'm not able to find anything proper on this. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like rclone or s3cmd to sync the Cloud Object Storage buckets to a linux server and then use those same tools to send them to the new Cloud Object Storage account.

https://mpcarl.github.io/rclone-cos
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/connecting-cos-s3-using-s3cmd

Comment: I am using the object storage as a Service, not as infrastructure. So there is nothing to see in the Softlayer portal. And the tool you mentioned needs the object storage to be created as Infra. Is there anything for the Object storage as service ?

Comment: Neither tool requires the SoftLayer version of COS. You simply need to generate HMAC credentials to use with the tools. https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/iam/service-credentials.html#service-credentials - Step 3 is the important part. This will allow for the creation of a Secret Key and Access Key that tools like rclone and s3cmd require.

Comment: I tried creating a new set of credentials by adding the HMAC option, but still getting the same credential list as the one without HMAC. This is the list of items I'm getting in creds after making HMAC as true

{
  "auth_url": "****",
  "project": "****",
  "projectId": "****",
  "region": "****",
  "userId": "****",
  "username": "****",
  "password": "****",
  "domainId": "****",
  "domainName": "****",
  "role": "admin"
}

Comment: I don't believe you are generating the right credentials. Following the guide you will get credentials that look like this https://dsc.cloud/quickshare/Screenshot_2018-03-13_13_11_26_e7YcO7.png